# angular-dual-listbox - Hide Buttons

Tags: css, angular5

I am using https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox, and it works like a charm. However, I need to hide the Add/Remove buttons, but I haven't been able to. The component lacks this functionality, so the author suggests to do it through css. I tried to do that, but failed. Here's my css:

```
button.btn-block {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I did this, in order to overwrite the following (hence the '!important'):

```
button.btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

which is included in https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox/blob/master/lib/src/dual-list.component.css. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got the answer. I asked the author, and he helped me out, as you may see here: https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox/issues/36

It took me a while to figure out what he meant by "app's base styles". I ended up creating a file called "hide.scss" which contains the lines he provided, in a new folder "/src/assets/scss/core/dual-list-box"

hide.scss

```
div.dual-list div.listbox button[name=addBtn],
div.dual-list div.listbox button[name=removeBtn],
div.dual-list div.listbox div.button-bar {
 display: none;
}
```

I referenced it from file2.scss, which is located in "/src/assets", like this:

```
@import "core/dual-list-box/hide";
```

Finally, file2.scss needs to be included in "styles" within .angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "./assets/scss/file2.scss"
  ],
```

Well, that's pretty much it. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Well I used the below in the component's scss file that I pulled the dual-list into.  Key being the `:host ::ng-deep`.  That moved and styled the add and remove buttons to be in the center in-between the two columns.

```
<div class="row margin-bottom-25px">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <dual-list [source]="source" [(destination)]="confirmed" [key]="key" [display]="display" height="500px"></dual-list>
   </div>
</div>

:host ::ng-deep {
  .point-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 275px;
    width: 115px !important;
    left: calc(50% - 58px);
  }
  .point-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 210px;
    width: 115px !important;
    left: calc(50% - 58px);
  }

  div.record-picker::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb, .record-picker li:first-child, .record-picker li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
  }

  .dual-list {
    > .listbox {
      width: calc(100% - 65px) !important;
      > .record-picker {
        width: calc(100% - 65px);
        border: 2px solid #000000;
        border-radius: 0;
        cursor: default;
      }
      &:nth-child(2) > .record-picker {
        float: right;
      }
    }
    .button-bar {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by hiding the buttons in the css file like this:

> ::ng-deep .pull-left {   display: none; }
>
> ::ng-deep .pull-right {   display: none; }

where pull-left is for the **all** button and pull-right for **none**.